# How to make UISearch to show up on the left like usual in IOS 7>?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

In IOS 7, `UISearchBar` is centered. What about if I want it to the left like in IOS 6? I think I saw one of my `UISearchBar` to be left aligned. However, I do not know how to achieve that

[image]

[image]

So I want the `UISearchBar` on the second picture to be just like the `UISearchBar` in the first picture.

I can't see alignment option in `UISearchBar` at all and have forgotten how I got the top picture to be left aligned. The top picture shows that left aligned `UISearchBar` is possible.

Comment: seems like in the first screenshot there is actually some text in the search bar. See that the clear button is there.

Comment: Give some white space in right of placeholder text

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19304599/2574939

Answer (score 0):

In the first screenshot, it seems like you have given text instead of placeholder. That is why it is left aligned. Please notice that there is a clear text button appeared in that screenshot. Secondly, once the user starts typing, the text will be left aligned, so it won't be much of a trouble.