# Unable to left align magnifying glass icon in search bar ios 7

Tags: ios7, uisearchbar

I need to left align the magnifying glass icon in UISearchBar in iOS 7. I have tried many things posted here and there but so far I am unable to achieve this.

--Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Customise the searcher instead of you already use.

```
UITextField *txfSearchField = [looksearchbar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    [txfSearchField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [txfSearchField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
    [txfSearchField setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
    [txfSearchField setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchbar_bgImg.png"]];
    [txfSearchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
    //txfSearchField.layer.borderWidth = 8.0f;
    //txfSearchField.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    txfSearchField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    txfSearchField.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeNever;
```

Try this.

Comment: This seems to simply make the icon disappear on iOS7 and iOS8, rather than left align.

Comment: For Swift-3 Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289406/uisearchbar-search-icon-isnot-left-aligned-in-ios7/41976067#41976067