# UISearchBar magnify glass icon position change

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

Is it possible to change the magnify glass icon in `uisearchbar` to left align. If possible, how would one approach this?

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289406/uisearchbar-search-icon-isnot-left-aligned-in-ios7/41976067#41976067

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `setPositionAdjustment:forSearchBarIcon:`, using probably a value of `-1`/`-0` or a large value equal to the width of the field. Don't have a system to try it on, but that should work I think.