# how to specifiy location of a search icon in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

Not a full-time iOS dev and just need to make this fix.

I am trying to use a UISearchBar with a UISearchController and it looks like this:

[image]

I have the following code and think that the highlighted code should fix this but not even sure how I would call it:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchBar.placeholder = "here i am"
    searchBar.sizeToFit()

     //searchBar.setPositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 30, vertical: 30), forSearchBarIcon: )

  }
```

I'd like for the icon to either be on the left or right. How would I achieve that?

Comment: I had faced this kind of issue, I tried for few hours and did not get success and at last i just did one trick to make it left align, So the trick was Give more white space to your place holder text, so it will align the text to left along with the search icon. Hope it helps and let me know if any other issue, i can help you

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289406/uisearchbar-search-icon-isnot-left-aligned-in-ios7/41976067#41976067